# Create SVG element using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I am using Vanilla Javascript. I have couple of external svg files that I add in my code. I want to create the following code dynamically using javascript. Here, the rock can be also paper of scissor. How do I do that?

```
<svg class="paper" id="paper" viewBox="0 0 50 50">
   <image width="50" height="50" xlink:href="images/icon-paper.svg"/>
</svg>
```

I tried this and createElementNS but neither of them worked.

```
let yourSVG = document.createElement('svg');
yourSVG.class = yourObject;
yourSVG.id = yourObject;
yourObject.viewBox = "0 0 50 50";
let yourImage = document.createElement('image');
yourImage.width = "50";
yourImage.height = "50";
yourImage.setAttribute('xlink:href' ,"image/icon-"+yourObject+".svg");
yourSVG.appendChild(yourImage);
document.getElementById('your-object-div').appendChild(yourSVG);
```

Comment: Why are you trying to wrap an <image /> in <svg>? You should be good just with the <image /> alone, put your svg file in the src attribute